# Appending a list of dataframes to a list of dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I was hoping to discover an easy solution but I have not been able to come across one. Lets say I have a two lists of 4 dataframes each. Each item of the list is a dataframe. One list is called

```
list_of_df1
```

the other is called

```
list_of_df2
```

I am wondering if there is away to append the dataframes from one list into the other list. The end goal is to have one combined list with all 8 dataframes. I am sorry I did not provided sample data. I am hoping it is an easy line of code.

This is what I tried:

```
list_of_df1.append(list_of_df2)
list_of_df1.insert(list_of_df2)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As simple as:

```
list_of_df1 += list_of_df2
```

This is actually *extremely slightly* more efficient than using `extend()`, since it doesn't include the overhead of a function call.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly the easy solution I was looking for!

Comment: @Jake Glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 5):

Considering `list_of_df1` and `list_of_df2` are lists:

```
list_of_df1.extend(list_of_df2)
```

Comment: Thank you! This code works but I will be using the solution with just adding the two lists together.

Answer (score 4):

Try `pd.concat(frames)`

```
import pandas as pd

d1 = {'ID': [10,20,40,50], 'Name': ["Bob", "John","test","Foo"]}   
d2 = {'ID': [10,20,40,50], 'Name': ["Bob", "John","test","Foo"]}   
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)

frames = [df1, df2]
result = pd.concat(frames)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
ID  Name
 10   Bob
 20  John
 40  test
 50   Foo
 10   Bob
 20  John
 40  test
 50   Foo
```

If you have list of DFs, then the solution posted by @ruohola is the one that you are looking for.

Comment: I think this will be valid if he wants one dataframe that has the contents of all the dataframes in the list, but he is saying that he wants a list of all dataframes.

Comment: Okay let me update the answer. THanks. I thought he is saying list means list of data inside a dataframe.

Comment: This doesn't do what the OP asks.

Answer (score 1):

The starred expression remove the brackets of the list.

```
[*list_df1, *list_df2]
```

Probably not the most efficient though.